# Regex for date where month is 1 or 2 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I've searched and didn't see this answered so I hope this isn't a repeat / duplicate question.

I'm extracting a date from a string, but moths and days maybe 1 digit or 2 digits.  That is, it can be:
- "1/1/2018"
- "12/1/2018"
- "1/12/2018"
- "12/12/2018"

I've seen how to Regex where the numbers are constant expected size - or padded with zero

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d
```

but how do I make the first digit as optional.  And if the first digit is there, how to grab both of them.

Answer (score 2):

To stay with your idea

```
(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d
```

Or you could just make the leading zero for days and month optional

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d
```

Where the question mark is defined as "Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed", see https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

Comment: Glad I could help! @HuckleberryCarignan it would be great if you could accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+` quantifier to match 1 or more of a preceding items. In your case, `[0-9]+` (or `\d+`) would match 1 or 12 or 2018.

Comment: like: (\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex.

```
\d+/\d+/-\d{4}
```

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question with existing answers it is useful to explain what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple way to extract date

```
function extractDate(dateString){
  var tempArray = dateString.split("/");
  var dateVal = tempArray[0];
  var monthVal = tempArray[1];
  var yearVal = tempArray[2];

  console.log(dateVal);
  console.log(monthVal);
  console.log(yearVal);

}

//Demo 1
extractDate("1/1/2018");

//Demo 2
extractDate("1/12/2018");


//Demo 3
extractDate("12/12/2018");
```

[Plunker Link for testing](http://plnkr.co/edit/YUh2eIpDdvxvXHAUoJbA?p=preview)